# Storing Steam Game Data from Steam API into MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, steam

I'm trying to insert data from a steam user with CS:GO stats into a MySQL Database using PHP. I need the `name` and `value` values from the `stats` array inserted into the MYSQL which I'm going to display in a Android application but I am unsure of how exactly to do it.

Code:

```
<?php
    $con = new mysqli('mysql6.000webhost.com','a2689951_Cheesy','ansmh1997', 'a2689951_mSicx');
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        echo mysqli_connect_error();
        exit;
    }             

    $stats = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=<key>&steamid=76561198050187807");
    $json = json_decode($stats, true);
    $stats = array();
    foreach ($content['playerstats']['stats'] as $stat) {
        $stats[$stat["name"]] = $stat["value"];
    }

    $insert = "INSERT INTO user (total_kills, total_deaths) VALUES (?, ?)";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($insert);
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $total_kills, $total_deaths);
?>
```

API example output:

```
{
    "playerstats": {
        "steamID": "76561198050187807",
        "gameName": "ValveTestApp260",
        "stats": [
            {
                "name": "total_kills",
                "value": 35179
            },
            {
                "name": "total_deaths",
                "value": 30241
            },
            {
                "name": "total_time_played",
                "value": 2444377
            },
            // ...
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also state your actual question!

Comment: That looking better?

Comment: You should explicitly stated the part you're having trouble with. Otherwise, it's very broad question. I tried to answer it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I think your insert statement needs to be inside the foreach, try this.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("mysql6.000webhost.com", "a2689951_steam", "password", "a2689951_playerdata");

$stats = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=(MyKey)&steamid=(PlayerID)");
$json = json_decode($stats, true);
$stats = array();
foreach ($content['playerstats']['stats'] as $stat) {
    $stats[$stat["name"]] = $stat["value"];
    $total_kills = $stats["total_kills"];
    $total_deaths = $stats["total_deaths"];

    $insert = "INSERT INTO user (total_kills, total_deaths) VALUES ('$statement', 'siss', $total_kills, $total_deaths)";
    if ($con->query($insert) === TRUE) {
        $response = array();
        json_encode($response);
        return json_encode($response["success"]);

    } else {
        return "Error: <br>" . $con->error;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to get into the habit of doing, since you're a beginner:

- Don't use the `mysql`-functions in PHP. Use [`mysqli`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead (it even supports object-orientet notation!)
- The way you have your `INSERT`-statement set up makes your vornable to [SQL Injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use a ["prepared statement"](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.
- To "return" data from a PHP script (that is, send it directly to the browser), you need to use `echo` instead of `return`.
- You have this line in your code: `json_encode($response)`, where `$response` is an empty array. This line won't do anything. the `json_encode()`-function returns a String that contains the JSON-representation of whatever you give it. It does not change it!
- I removed the API-Key from the URL you had in your example, since sharing the key publicly is not a good idea and can result in Valve banning your key (for example if malicious people use it to send requests to the API).

---

Now for your actual problem:

```
foreach ($json->playerstats->stats as $stat) {
    $stats[$stat["name"]] = $stat["value"];
    $total_kills = $stats["total_kills"];
    $total_deaths = $stats["total_deaths"];
```

I think there might be some confusion as to what part of this code is actually repeated by the loop. It's **not** just the first line, it's the entire body (enclosed by the `{}`-brackets).

The problem is that you will only get the first entry from the JSON into the `$stats`-array, which would be `total_kills`. But you want all of them, so your loop should run over this part alone:

```
foreach ($content['playerstats']['stats'] as $stat) {
    $stats[$stat["name"]] = $stat["value"];
}
// Continue as you did...
```

This will then bring the entire data from your request into the format that you expect, so the second access to `$stats` will work properly.

Comment: Nothing uploaded to database unfortunately, check edited post for new code

Comment: In your new code, the variables `$total_kills` and `$total_deaths` are never assigned. If you're getting any errors, please include those, too.